# Reactjs web thermal printer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I have installed a react web app, my goal is to print with thermal printer, printing a component of text value (like a hello world text) when user click a button from web browser, I used package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer, but when I see the example is different like making a component of react, and I got confused how to trigger button click from component to send queue to print with the thermal printer.
Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: The example is for using the library. You can't just copy and paste and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a very basic idea as to how you'd want to go about it. Let's start with a basic component:

```
const printer = require( 'node-thermal-printer' ); 
class TPrinter extends React.Component {

  constructor( props ) {
      super( props );
      this._printer = printer.init( {
          type: 'epson',
          interface: '/dev/usb/lp0'
      } );
   }

   handleOnClick() {
       this._printer.alignCenter();
       this._printer.println("Hello world");
       this._printer.cut();
       this._printer.execute( ( err ) => {
           if( err ) { return console.log( err ); }
           console.log( 'Done!' );
       } );

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={ this.handleOnClick }></button>
    )
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<TPrinter />
```

And it'll show a button, which when clicked, do what you want it to do. Now, of course, you can make it a lot fancier by using `props` and using those in the `printer.init()` function, but you get the basic gist.

Comment: hello thx for ur guide, but when i try the code there is an error like this :

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-thermal-printer/interfaces/file.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in etc

Comment: Check the code for the module `file`. You'll get the problem. It's pretty simple.

Comment: I think the node-themal-printer is meant to run on node. In the browser the module fs is not available.

Comment: That is the reason but I wanted him to figure it out since he literally just copied the code.

Comment: Is it possible to run this from the browser at all? If it’s not, what’s the point of making a react component that depends on this library?

Comment: @Osuriel - yes, and no. The basic premise I am trying to demonstrate here is that as long as you have that character device (`/dev/usb/lp0`), you can send commands regardless of where you start this from. I was able to get this to work if I defined a simple TCP proxy over the character device and changed a little bit of code in the core library to allow for HTTP requests as opposed to directly writing byte sequences on the device.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I need to thermal-print from a react application. Did you ever get this to work out????